# How to get information of opened files in xv6 regarding readable and piped/regular

Tags: linux, operating-system, xv6

I am doing a project in which i need to implement a system call which prints all the files opened by all processes but i am unable to get the information of readable and piped/regular. Below is my code

```
int
lsof(void)
{
    struct proc *p;
        sti();
        acquire(&ptable.lock);
        cprintf("name \t pid \t type \t read|write \n");
      struct file* fp;
        int readable = 0;
      int piped = 0;
      for (p=ptable.proc; p<&ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
          readable = 0;
          piped = 0;
          fp = (struct file*) &p->ofile;
          if(fp->readable){
            readable = 1;
          }
          if(fp->type == 1){
            piped = 1;
          }
          if(readable == 1 && piped == 1){
            cprintf("%s \t %d \t piped \t R  \n", p->name, p->pid);
          }
          else if(readable == 0 && piped == 1){
            cprintf("%s \t %d \t piped \t W  \n", p->name, p->pid);
          }
          else if(readable == 1 && piped == 0){
            cprintf("%s \t %d \t regular \t R  \n", p->name, p->pid);
          }
          else if(readable == 0 && piped == 0){
            cprintf("%s \t %d \t regular \t W  \n", p->name, p->pid);
          }

        }

    release (&ptable.lock);
    return 1;
}
```

i am getting the error that **dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct file’
           if(fp->readable){**

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you use:

- `ptable`: since it's internal to `proc.c`, you need to put you code at the end of `proc.c` (or export it nicely)
- `struct file`: you need to include `file.h`, but this file depends itself on `fs.h` (for `NDIRECT`) and `sleeplock.h` (for `struct sleeplock`).

So, you need to:

- add

  ```
  #include "fs.h"
  #include "sleeplock.h"
  #include "file.h"
  ```

  before `lsof(void)`
- put all this code at the end of `proc.c`

Answer (score -1):

The posting reads like a compiler error.  Prepend a line within your source file that includes a header with the definition of struct file; eg:

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
```

Comment: i included #include "file.h" but after adding it, i am getting like more errors.

Comment: Does "file.h" contain the definition for struct file ?  New errors are probably caused by references to other structs or similar.  Find the other defs and #include before "file.h"